# Flutter Switch List tile loop not changing/moving when clicked

Tags: flutter

I have a for loop in my code that populates the field _skill from the field allSkills using data from a database. In the same loop I populate instances of SwitchListTile into skillDisplay from each instance of _skills. I have all the switchListTile on screen but they are all stuck on off/false and I cannot activate any of them. I placed the if statement around it to make sure that the code wouldn't continuously get called on after _skills was populated but that didn't work.

Sorry for not showing all the code but this is where the bug is occurring, I believe.

```
List<String> allSkills = [];
Map<String, bool> _skills = {};
List<SwitchListTile> skillDisplay = [];
```

Populate allSkills prior to code below with always >1 values from a database after selecting requirements in other widgets from a step.
Code is inside build, within an onValue of a DropdownButtonFormField widget. have tested and only
executes once so its not constantly re-occurring.

```
if(_skills.length > 1){
    for (String s in allSkills) {
       _skills[s] = false;//populates map
       //create switch list tile instances
       SwitchListTile x = SwitchListTile(
         title: Text('$s'),
         activeColor: _skills[s]!
             ? Colors.green
             : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        value: _skills[s]!,
        onChanged: (value) {
             setState(() => _skills[s] = value);
             });
             //adds to my switch list tile list and display it in a later step
        skillDisplay.add(x);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_skills[s] = false;//populates map
```

will reset them all to false after you click on a SwitchListTile. I don't know why this is here, but this is the problem.